# Context passing a string through the URL

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to pass a molfile as a string to my template that is being generated from a SMILES string so that I can display a chemical structure.

```
class CompoundView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'CompoundDisplay.html'
    model = Compound

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CompoundView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(self.object)
        comp_pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        if context_object_name:
            context[context_object_name] = self.object
        comp_id = Compound.objects.get(pk=comp_pk)
        cursor = Smile.objects.get(compound_fk=comp_id.compound_ID)
        smile = cursor.smiles
        m = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smile)
        mol = Chem.MolToMolBlock(m)
        correct_mol = mol.replace('\n', '\\n')
        context['calc_factors'] = cursor
        context['mols'] = correct_mol
        context.update(kwargs)
        return context
```

Everything is working fine except the mol string, which is getting passed through GET to the page ending up with this in the url, which obviously isn't working. Is there a way in a CBV to load this as POST? Or is there somewhere else I’m going wrong?

> [15/Jan/2015 11:20:27] "GET /compounds/compound/298/RDKit%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2044%2045%20%200%20%200%20%200%20%200%20%200%20%200%20%200%20%200999%20V2000%20%20%20%200.0000%20%20%20%200.0000%20%20%20%200.0000%20O%20%20%200%20%200%20%200%20%200%20%200%20%....2043%20%201%20%200%2043%2044%20%202%20%200%2043%20%202%20%201%20%200%2039%2035%20%201%20%200M%20%20END HTTP/1.1" 404 18005

Comment: Your problem isn't in this code. There's no reason a context variable would show up in the URL. What is making that request?

Comment: There's a link you follow that goes to /compounds/compound/<pk>. I can't figure out how it would be pulling the string into it.

Comment: What happens if you manually go to /compounds/compound/298

Comment: I get the same problem
>[15/Jan/2015 14:13:15] "GET /compounds/compound/298/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10220
[15/Jan/2015 14:13:15] "GET /compounds/compound/298/RDKit%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2044%2045%20%200%20%200%20%200%20....2043%20%202%20%201%20%200%2039%2035%20%201%20%200M%20%20END HTTP/1.1" 404 18189

Comment: It seems like a redirect problem to me. At some point do you have something like `return HttpResponseRedirect(mols)`?

Comment: No, that's the whole CBV I posted in the beginning. Would I just put that in the get_context_data() function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68923/discussion-between-daniel-robinson-and-mjpeterson).

Comment: I think the problem may be these lines: `if context_object_name: context[context_object_name] = self.object`.  Are you sure you want to set it to the object? It should usually be something like "compound".